# Types of equilibria of a chaotic system

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory, jacobian, stability-theory

Is it correct to use the Jacobian matrix in determining the types of equlibria of a non-linear chaotic system of smooth ODEs? If not, is there a general approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stability analysis of equilibrium points of non-linear systems can get quite difficult. If the Jacobi matrix has eigenvalues with real part bounded away from zero, then you're fine; the type of stability is of the non-linear system is the same as in the linearized case, however the structure might still be different. If the real part of one of the eigenvalues is zero, then even small non-linearities can change the stability of the point. In this case different techniques have to be applied. Unfortunately there is no general approach.

Comment: And so if around each of my equilibria the eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix have non-zero real part then it is perfectly correct to apply the regular conclusions of the stability of said equilibria?

Comment: Yes, but bear in mind that if an eigenvalues lies on a bifurcation line, then the structure of the equilibrium need not be the same in the non-linear and linearized case. In this case we only know that the asymptotic behaviour is the same.